# How to force angular material follow the ionic v5 dark mode switch

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic4, ionic5

im trying to develop my first App and i got stuck with this issue.
when the device is in dark mode ionic automatically switches to dark mode as well.
but the angular material doesn't change its color scheme which keeps the text dark.

Thanks is Advance.

Comment: In the scheme color in variables , change it from dark to light

Answer (score 0):

if you use global variables for giving color through all the app it will change when you switch and there will be no problem. the problem is with using non-ionic variables to color them.

Comment: how do i set the ionic veriable to the angular material theme thats what i cant figure out

Comment: @AlexSkiba use `mode="md"` for material design and `color="variable-name"`

Comment: @AlexSkiba how long do you use ionic?

Comment: I don’t understand your question

Comment: @AlexSkiba when do you started to use ionic? a month? a year?

Comment: Touched it like at ionic 2  and now just starting to get back at it. I don’t see how it’s relevant to the wuestion

Comment: @AlexSkiba I asked it to see how much you are familiar with ionic.

Comment: not that much i know the very basic things and trying to expand my knowledge. Should i try to set the material template with the ionic variables?

Comment: @AlexSkiba the material theme is a theme that is built-in in ionic. just add `mode='md'` to your tags. and then you can use attribute color (for example: `color='primary'`) to color them.

Comment: the problem is with ios i guess i will just over write the dark mode colors i guess